# Android: how to restrict access to ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, restrictions

Is it possible to add a filter to a content provider to make it accept only requests coming from a set of known application IDs?
For example, if com.domain1.app1 and com.domain2.app2 are two app that I trust I'd like to make them read my data. Any other application should be kept outside.
Something like intent filter but related to incoming request from other applications.

I know about the same signing key but it's not what I need.

Comment: There's nothing baked into Android for this. You could try `Binder.getCallingUid()` from inside a relevant `ContentProvider` method (e.g., `query()`) and see if it gives you the UID of the caller. If so, you can use that with `PackageManager` to determine the application ID(s) associated with that UID. But, I forget if `Binder.getCallingUid()` works from within a `ContentProvider`, which is why I'm unsure if this will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Content Providers - Is it possible to restrict the provider to a set of applications not written by me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132360/android-content-providers-is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-provider-to-a-set-of). Anyway according to [ContentProvider and getCallingUid()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/gl9pxKjH6yE) using `Binder.getCallingUid()` should work.

Answer (score 2):

> If a provider's application doesn't specify any permissions, then other applications have no access to the provider's data. However, components in the provider's application always have full read and write access, regardless of the specified permissions.

As seen [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions).